# How to play an audio file at a specific interval using Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, audio-player

As normal:

```
player=audioplayer(snd1,FS1);
play(player);

%let as suppose that sound duration is 10 seconds
% and I wanted to play the sound from second 5 or 7... 
%   .. depending on the input of user(and using audioplayer libraries)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify the `start` and `stop` using the [**play(playerObj,[start,stop])**](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audioplayer.play.html) function:

```
load handel;
playerObj = audioplayer(y,Fs);
start = 1;
stop = playerObj.SampleRate * 3;

play(playerObj,[start,stop]);
```

Alternatively, you can calculate a subsample of the total data and feed this to the [**audioplayer**](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audioplayer.html):

```
load handel;
% y = data
% Fs = frequency = number of datapoints per second
% so calculate begin and end time using the sampling frequency:
totalTime = size(y,1)/Fs;  % all data divided by sampling frequency
beginTime = round(5*Fs);   % 5 seconds
endTime = round(7*Fs);     % 7 seconds

% playing full audio:
% player = audioplayer(y, Fs);
% play(player);

% playing only part of audio:
player = audioplayer(y(beginTime:endTime,:), Fs);
play(player);
```

Comment: Well that's a bust lol. Just about to write this. +1.  BTW, to adapt to the multi-channel case, you may want to use `y(...,:)`, instead of `y(...,1)`.  You may also want to ensure that `beginTime` and `endTime` are integers.  If the OP wants to scrub through the audio, there may be a case where the beginning and ending seconds are floating point.

Comment: @rayryeng Haha sorry :) Happens to me too sometimes! Good tips btw, have edited my answer accordingly!

Comment: I'm not the one who asked it :)  rayryeng != 0xFFFFFF

Answer (score 2):

The `PLAY` method for audioplayer supports additional input argument called `[startSample stopSample]`. So if you want to play audio between 5 and 7 seconds, the range you have to specify is `[player.SampleRate*5 player.SampleRate*7]`.

Comment: Didn't know this. Interesting.